# Помогите разобраться в действии кода

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+.\\d+\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(s[i]);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        res[i] =  matcher.group();
    }
}
```

Вот как понял я: запускается массив, который проверяет каждую строчку массива `s[i]`. Метод (правильно я его называю?) `Pattern` осуществляет поиск по і-той строке. `Pattern.compile` — это, грубо говоря, трафарет того, что мы ищем в строке (тут числа типа `double`). `pt.matcher(s[i])` сравнивает строку с трафаретом (?), а `while (matcher.find()) {res[i] =  matcher.group();}` — пока есть совпадения (то есть пока найдено, то идет запись в массив `res[i]`). Совсем не понял, как работает «трафарет»: `\\b\\d+.\\d+\\b`

Объясните, что не так сказано, пожалуйста.

Comment: 1. По каждому классу есть документация. Читайте.
2. Исследуйте повдеение кода в отладчике.
3. Модифицируйте код и смотрите, что меняется.

Следующий непонятный вам код вы тоже сюда на разбор выложите?

Comment: Да, выложу сюда на разбор. Людям нужен рейтинг, мне нужна помощь. Мне помогают, я повышаю их рейтинг.

Comment: про вопрос выше: 1. нужно изучать. а 2. никто ничего не запрешает выкладывать сюда по теме чего понять не можешь, если был сорказм в ваших словах, то ответ нужно искать в себе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Метод (правильно я его называю?) Pattern

класс Pattern

> Pattern.compile - это, грубо говоря, трафарет того, что мы ищем в строке (тут числа типа double).

сам по себе compile - это как раз метод, а вот в аргументах у него действительно регулярное выражение (или шаблон, хотя называть регулярным выражением корректней)

Про регулярные выражения можно почитать здесь (или в любой выдаче гугла по соответствующему запросу): http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Конкретно эта регулярка расшифровывается так:

\b - boundary, граница слова  
\d - цифра (или диапазон 0-9)  
+ - квантификатор, указывающий на повторение символа 1 или более раз  
. - любой символ, кроме перевода строки. Здесь, очевидно, имелась в виду просто точка, но забыли поставить предшествующий экранирующий слэш  

То есть регулярка расшифровывается примерно так: граница слова/одна или несколько цифр/любой символ/одна или несколько цифр/граница слова

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: @111xbot111, если ответ вам помог, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.